# Asynchronous calls to server using ASP .Net MVC 5 and AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one HTTP post call in angularjs which takes around 7-8 secs to complete the task. The url is action method of one controller in MVC. As it is taking a lot of time I don't want my user to wait for this operation but can navigate to any other page or even can continue with different operations on the same page. once the operation gets complete, it will notify user for either the success or failure.Currently any other http post waits for this post to get complete before showing it's respective result. I need help in what can be done for this scenario. What is the best approach? I checked this below link and I see some suggestions. Will it be helpful? link- http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc

AngularJS Code-

```
$http({
     url: key_Url_Generate,
     method: Post,
     params: $scope.PlanDetails
            }).then(function (result) {
                     //Notify user for success or failure
                                      }
```

Controller Action Method-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateLtdQuote(LTD_PlanDetailsVM ltdPlanDetailsVM)
{
// time consuming operation here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, async, at least in terms of C#, merely allows the thread to be returned to the pool while it is in a wait state, i.e. waiting for something like an external service to respond. It does not make the action return quicker. In fact, if *anything* async can make things slower, as it adds overhead. If the endpoint being hit by your AJAX does anything that puts the thread in a wait state, where it's doing nothing but waiting for some external process to complete, then you should use async on it, but only because it allows the server to more efficiently use resources. It won't make anything happen any quicker, though.

Async, in terms of JavaScript, is a little different, as JavaScript process *will* continue. That is why you have a callback for AJAX requests. When whatever resource is being accessed remotely finally responds, the callback will be invoked, but other things can still happen in the meantime. This actually makes your question *more* confusing, though, because by using AJAX, your page should *not* be blocked at all and the user should still be able to interact with the page and do whatever they want. The only way this wouldn't occur is if you're running AJAX synchronously, which is actually a little hard to do by accident, and should definitely be avoided.

Comment: Hi Chris, Is my AJAX call running synchronously. I am using the same angularjs code that I have written in my question.